# avoid duplicating values in a range

Tags: php, mysql

note: "I am a novice at this.  i need a mysql query that will not permit users to put in numbers in a range that already exist in a database. I am dealing with cards here and the amount of cards to be manufactured by user1 will be inserted via create page before he/she commence. while user2 can commence on another machine but without prior info abt where user1 started from. so for example if user2 attempts to choose to start anything from 1,2,3,4,5,6, up to 2530 a **trigger or error** should occur which prevents them from duplicating the range already done by user1.

As advised, i have a "number_from" and a "number_to" column in the table. find what i am trying to achive in the table below

Also note that duplicating cards should depend on the job_number because the unique identifier for jobs is the job_number which can never be same for any job.

I have asked this question before but no clarity with the solution or maybe because i dont have experience in writing triggers or stored procedure. like i said earlier "i am a novice" and my future depends on this

```
id |user_id| number_from | number_to | client | cardtype  | job_number | job_quant |status
1  | smith |      1      |   2530    | queens |inspiration| j290122    | 5000      |nt done
2  | john  |   2531      |   4000    | queens |inspiration| j290122    | 5000      |nt done
4  | kenny |      1      |   1500    |seabirds|   love    | j300011    | 1500      | done
3  | wayne |   4001      |   5000    | queens |inspiration| j290122    | 5000      | done
```

user_id is a foreign key

```
id | user | password
1  |smith | ********
2  |john  | ********
3  |wayne | ********
4  |kenny | ********
5  |laura | ********
```

so far all i have an insert query that adds data to database.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 // process the form
$user_id = (int) $_POST["user_id"];
$number_from = $_POST["number_from"];
$number_to = $_POST["number_to"];
$client = mysql_prep($_POST["client"]);
$cardtype = $_POST["cardtype"];
$job_number = $_POST["job_number"];
$job_quantity = $_POST["job_quantity"];
$status = $_POST["status"];

$query = "INSERT INTO jobs (";
$query .= " user_id, number_from, number_to, client, cardtype, job_number, job_quantity, status";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= " '{$user_id}', '{$number_from}', '{$number_to}', '{$client}', '{$card_type}', '{$job_number}', '{$job_quantity}', '{$status}'";
$query .= ")";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result) {
// success
   $_SESSION["message"] = "job created.";
   redirect_to("manage_job.php"); 
  } else {
// failure  
   $_SESSION["message"] = "job creation failed.";
   redirect_to("new_job.php");
  }  
} 
?>
```

Comment: Query before using `mysqli_num_rows()`. If something matches, then `// do something` else `// do something else`

Comment: despite all the great answers that has been provided, I think @Fred's "dummy" approach is the better solution for YOU. For a sql novice, it's usually not a very good idea to attempt to optimize everything(use complex sql) and hiding logics(triggers). It'll be better if you do the query->check in php->modify data->insert approach because you will understand 100% of the logic and all of the logic are located in the same file/piece of code. That will greatly increase your ability to maintain/enhance the program in future without external help.

Comment: @JackyCheng I couldn't agree with you more. It's best to start and learn from the ground up, then move on to more complex methods as time progresses. I see it all too often where someone posts some pretty fancy and high performance code, only to ask "how do I work this?". That's the the classic "I just got my driver's license, and I bought me a Top Fuel Dragster and an F1 racing car".

Comment: @JackyCheng (continued)... It took me the better part of 3 months to study SQL, another 2 after that to try out some code and test-test-test. Only when I felt good and ready, was I able to produce manageable code that I could understand, that way if anything goes haywire, I'll have a better understanding as to what went wrong, or am having difficulties with. Cheers

Comment: Can @Fred-ii- break it down please. as in i cant write the query to fit

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I have rewritten the answer following the clarification of @benga and @gview in the comments.

To avoid the overlapping you can do it via triggers or by writing application logic (in PHP in your case). In both cases you would need as parameters `new_number_from` and `new_number_to`. The former is the **number_from** value of the new entry. The latter is the **number_to** value of the new entry. You would also need `new_job_number`.

The query below returns all rows that overlap with the range specified by the parameters `$new_number_from` and `$new_number_to` for job with id `$job_number`

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 
  job_number=$jobNumber AND 
  number_from <= $new_number_to AND
  number_to >= $new_number_from
```

If you implement this using PHP, you could execute this query and check if any row is returned. If an empty resultset is returned then there is no conflict. Otherwise there is a conflict.

NOTE: You may prefer to get the count (`SELECT COUNT(*)`) instead of returning lines (`SELECT *`)

Comment: That is not the problem he's trying to solve.  He wants to avoid rows inserted that contain numbers in a range that has already been allocated.  Putting a unique index on the values does nothing to prevent that other than in the case of someone trying to insert exactly the same range.

Comment: @leonel machava wht you are suggesting wont avoid row data which are in range of 1,2,3,4,5 to say 2300 from been duplicated just specific number. pls i need help with this anybody that can help

Comment: @gview i believe u understand my explanation. pls can you help with the query?

Comment: thanks LeonelMachava am having a good feeling about your explanation but will the below be in my trigger?                                                        @SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 
  job_number=$jobNumber AND 
  number_from <= $new_number_to AND
  number_to >= $new_number_from

Comment: You will have to adapt it to the proper syntax of mysql triggers.

Comment: Please, post the trigger in your question.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL triggers and stored procedures are convoluted in my opinion.  You could however create a procedure and call it in a BEFORE trigger, passing the NEW.job_number, new.number_from and new.number_to, then querying.  Your code would then have to be modified to try..catch for your mysql error.

You could also do this procedurally (in PHP) by making a series of queries that do this:

```
LOCK TABLES jobs WRITE;

SELECT count(*) as countof FROM jobs
WHERE job_number = $job_number
AND (($number_from BETWEEN number_from AND number_to) OR ($number_to BETWEEN number_from AND number_to));

// Fetch the result, and if it's == 0, then you insert.

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

If you decide to use a trigger with a CALL Procedure(params...) technique, the internals of the query would be the same, only you'd be passing the NEW. variables to it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, personally I find this more readable...

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO jobs 
(user_id
,number_from
,number_to
,client
,cardtype
,job_number
,job_quantity
,status) VALUES 
('$user_id'
,'$number_from'
,'$number_to'
,'$client'
,'$card_type'
,'$job_number'
,'$job_quantity'
,'$status'
);
";
```

I've included inverted commas only because I don't which of your values are strings.

Comment: ok it looks neater but this does not solve the problem at hand. pls can you help?